# VueJS - prop / var assignment / when / how

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and having trouble with when / how to assign a prop value calculated using the a store object. I want to grab the id from the url (e.g. /location?locationid) and compare that against the locations object in the store to find the correct location (by location_id) and pass that matching object as prop to the child location component.

I'm not sure when to do the `curLoc` calculation currently in `created()`. I've tried doing it as a computed prop, with no luck. I've tried putting the calculation into a method and calling it on `created()` and `update()` and it works with a webpack update but not a page refresh.

```
<template>
  <div class="location-wrap">
    <main id="main" aria-label="content">
      <h2 class="c-section__title">{{ this.curLoc.location_name // get get location_name of undefined }}</h2>
      <div class="location">
        <Location v-bind:loc="curLoc" /> // I want curLoc to be accessible to this child Location component.
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Location from "@/components/Location";
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "location",
  components: {
    Location,
  },
  computed: mapState(["locations"]),
  data() {
    return {
      curLoc: {},
      locationId: "",
      locationName: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    // curLoc calculation
    let ref = location.href;
    this.locationId = ref.substring(ref.indexOf("?") + 1);
    this.locations.forEach(loc => { 
      if (loc.location_id === this.locationId) {
        this.curLoc = loc;
        console.log(this.curLoc); // nope
      }
    });
  },
  updated() {},
  methods: {}
};
</script>
```

Comment: try to initialize curLoc as curLoc{location_id: ""}, Bcz if suppose your if conditions fails if(loc.location_id === this.locationId) then curLoc.location_id will be undefined and inside the if condition assign this.curLoc = loc.location_id.
And this.locations is not defined here;

Comment: @Kirk Ross, can you print this.locations value in your created hook before the loop and show the output. If your locations are fetched from an API call inside store then they won't be available in the created hook. Let me know if that's the issue.

Comment: @Himanshu thank you. It's weird... when I console `this.locations` in the `created()` hook I get one of those `[__ob__: Observer]` objects. However, if I make a change and webpack refreshes the components, it prints the correct `(22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}... etc.`. If I console it from `updated()` it's always the `__ob__:Observer` object, even after webpack refresh.

Comment: @Himanshu this is part of a large complex app that I'm working on but didn't originally build so I don't refactor it too much and potentially create headaches in other components. The locations object is pulled from a database and doesn't change. It's used in some other components and prints fine in updated(), so I just need to trace the differences in the components I think.

Comment: You do not need to use `this` in template.
It shouldbe just `curLoc.location_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a computed property like this

```
currLoc() {
    /* remove currLoc from data */
   let currLoc = {};
   let ref = location.href;
   this.locationId = ref.substring(ref.indexOf("?") + 1);
   /* put check when initially locations isn't defined and can even use break */
   this.locations.forEach(loc => { 
     if (loc.location_id === this.locationId) {
        curLoc = loc;
        console.log(curLoc); // should print your currLoc
     }
   });
   return currLoc;
}
```

By making currrLoc a computed property we've ensured that it runs everytime the location changes. You can now use computed property in the template (currLoc and pass it as a prop)

Comment: @Kirk Ross, Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I changed `this.locationId` in the computed prop to just a local var because I was getting a no-side-effects error. The problem now is that `<Location :loc="currLoc" />` calls the computed property `currLoc()` before `this.locations` is available, so currLoc is undefined. I tried adding an `:if` to the child, i.e. `<Location :if="this.locations" :loc="currLoc" />` but no luck. I feel like I'm close.

Comment: @KirkRoss Did you mean v-if? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Comment: @KirkRoss Isn't cuuLoc getting triggered again when locations are defined. Can you confirm?

Comment: that worked! I thought `:if="foobar"` was an abbreviation of `v-if="foobar"`

Comment: @KirkRoss, Happy to help!!